# I have an iPhone 6S

Tags: software-update

Hello I have been searching for ways to update my apps & download without having to use a credit card which I don't have and I don't have the "none or Paypal" option in the payment section and I don't know what else to do. Is there any way without having those options that I can update my apps or even download any??

Answer (score 1):

1. Walk, drive, or hitch a ride to a store that sells iTunes Gift Cards
2. and buy one with your cash money
3. Enter Code # from card into iTunes
4. Purchase Software
5. Happiness! (Your results may vary).